# How to prompt the user with message when combo box item is changed

Tags: c#, combobox

I am new to C#, I am trying to prompt the user with a message once the `combobox` item is changed, but the below code doesn't work even though the `combobox` item is changed.

```
 namespace NormingPointTagProgrammer
{
public partial class normingPointTagProgrammer : Form
{
    public normingPointTagProgrammer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // User Message to start the tag programming
        MessageBox.Show("To Read the data programmed in a Tag, Click on READ Button\n" +
                        "To Write data into the tag, \n" +
                        "Please select the Data Format, under DATA TO PROGRAMMER frame.");
    } 

    private void dataFormatComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the user has decided to program the tag. Check the Data format selected by the user, and ask the user to
        // enter required fields based on the format selected.

        if (datFormatcomboBox.Text == "RSO")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Within DATA TO PROGRAMMER frame, under RSO DATA from DataBase Enter the following fields: \n" +
                            "Region (1-254),\n" +
                            "Segment (1-255),\n" +
                            "Offset (0 to 6553.5) and \n" +
                            "select Type dropdown Field, Under");
         }

        else if (datFormatcomboBox.Text == "INDEX")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Within DATA TO PROGRAMMER frame, under INDEX DATA from DataBase Enter the following fields: \n" +
                            "Region (255) and \n" +
                            "Index  (1-65535) ");
        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(datFormatcomboBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select the Data Format, under DATA TO PROGRAMMER frame.");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Required fields not entered by the user.\n" +
                            "Please enter the data to be programmed based on the Data Format selected");
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: is the breakpoint hitting in the method?

Comment: Did you try adding the event handler? Ex. `dataFormatComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += dataFormatComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;`

Comment: Nope the breakpoint doesn't hit

Comment: Then your `ComboBox` is probably not subscribed to the event. Do what @vbnet3d mentions in their comment. If you use VS, next time just double click the appropriate event in the properties window and it will be both generated and subscribed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your event is being subscribed to, a shorthand would be using the below for example,

```
ComboBoxChanged += dataFormatComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged();
```

Or,

```
ComboBoxChanged += new EventHandler(dataFormatComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);


// This will be called whenever the ComboBox changes:
      private void dataFormatComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         //Your datFormatcomboBox.Text logic here.
      }
```

Essentially, whatever is passed to ComboBoxChanged, use `e` to obtain the input of ComboBox text.

More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Hope that helps!